# How to convert UTC time to local timezones based on timezone column in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I've been trying to convert each UTC time back to the appropriate local timezone using standard SQL in GBQ, but couldn't find a good way to do it dynamically because I might have tons of different timezone name within the database. I'm wondering if anyone has an idea?

The table I have contains 2 different columns (see screenshot)

[image]

Comment: what the expected output?  - please clarify

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I'm hoping to have a new column called "local_time" if that makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.yourtable` AS (
  SELECT 'Pacific/Honolulu' timezone, TIMESTAMP '2020-03-01 03:41:27 UTC' UTC_timestamp UNION ALL
  SELECT 'America/Los_Angeles',  '2020-03-01 03:41:27 UTC'
)
SELECT *, 
  DATETIME(UTC_timestamp, timezone) AS local_time
FROM `project.dataset.yourtable`
```

with output

```
Row timezone            UTC_timestamp           local_time   
1   Pacific/Honolulu    2020-03-01 03:41:27 UTC 2020-02-29T17:41:27  
2   America/Los_Angeles 2020-03-01 03:41:27 UTC 2020-02-29T19:41:27
```